# how to curl login like this website using python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to log in this page using python but got some trouble in [Login](http://cip.chinatimes.com).

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
params = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
r = requests.post("http://cip.chinatimes.com/login_ws.asp", params)
print(r.cookies.get_dict())

s =session.get("http://cip.chinatimes.com/international/cip_cmd_result.asp")
print(s.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we get rid of everything that isn't important in the login form on http://cip.chinatimes.com/ we get:

```
<form name="frmMain" method="post" action="login_ws.asp" id="Form1">
  <input name="ID" type="text" class="txtbox" id="Text1">
  <input name="PWD" type="password" class="txtbox" id="Password1">
  <input type="image" src="images/login.gif">
  <input type="hidden" name="SYS" value="CIP" id="Hidden1">
  <input type="hidden" name="Login" value="登入" id="Hidden2">
</form>
```

Everything that has a `name` attribute you need to provide in your request. So it looks to my like your params should be:

```
params = {'ID': 'username', 'PWD': 'password', 'SYS': 'CIP', 'Login': '登入'}
```

Comment: Hi blueteeth, thanks for your reply.  I add all the input column but still can't login. I don't know how it works on authentication....

Comment: The `Login` value might change. Have you checked you are getting all the data from the page? I would suggest fetching the whole page, extracting the form, changing the ID and PWD, and then submitting it.